# unity.system; Не работают ивенты

Tags: c#, unity3d, события

Есть две части кода:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class cubeCollisionDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent scoreUp;
    public UnityEvent scoreDown;

    private string cubeName;
    private string[] cubeNameMassive;

    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.transform.tag == "sphere")
        {
            cubeName = gameObject.name;
            Destroy(GameObject.Find(gameObject.name));
            string nameToCount = gameObject.name.Split('(')[0];
            string[] cubeNameMassive = nameToCount.Split('/');
            string colour = cubeNameMassive[3];
            if (colour.Contains("red"))
            {
                scoreUp.Invoke();
            }
            else if (colour.Contains("green"))
            {
                scoreDown.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

и

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class scoringScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    static private int scoring = 0;

    public void scoringUpMethod()
    {
        scoring++;
        Debug.Log(scoring);
        GetComponent<Text>().text = "scoring: " + scoring.ToString();
    }
    public void scoringDownMethod()
    {
        scoring--;
        Debug.Log(scoring);
        GetComponent<Text>().text = "scoring: " + scoring.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: `GameObject.Find`, уж больно тяжелая операция, старайтесь избегать этого -это поможет вам в будущем. На счет ивентов, не понятно, что вы подразумеваете, `под не работают`? Задача не понятна, добавьте в свой вопрос, больше информации и ошибки если есть и что не получается, опишите более конкретно.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что Вы собственноручно написанным кодом при запуске игры удаляете свои настройки, заданные в редакторе:

Класс **cubeCollisionDetector** в методе `Start` заменяет ссылки, заданные в редакторе.

Условия

```
if (scoreUp != null)
    ...
if (scoreDown != null)
    ...
```

выполняются, т.к. Вы задали ссылки на методы в другом скрипте. Поэтому код работает должным образом - "затирает" старое значение, заданное Вами, на **new UnityEvent()**

Comment: Точно, до чего невнимательность доводит((

Comment: В любом случае. проблема остается. Я останавливал выполнение программы через дебаг. Я по шагам смотрел, как программа выполняется через дебаг. Во второй скрипт выполнение не переходит. Программа выполняет ```scoreUp.Invoke();``` и вместо перехода внутрь функции события продолжает выполнение в том-же скрипте.

Comment: Возможно ли в иерархии Вашего проекта удаление самого объекта кодом **Destroy(GameObject.Find(gameObject.name));**? Или у Вас несколько объектов с одинаковым именем? Возможно, удаляется объект, от которого Вы ожидаете **scoreUp.Invoke()**, т.е. объект с вашим компонентом **cubeCollisionDetector**